# 'Projectivization' of a map, or applying the preimage theorem to a projective variety

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, manifolds, differential-topology, smooth-manifolds

> Let $p: \mathbb C^{n+1}\rightarrow \mathbb C^m$ be a homogeneous
>   polynomial map. Show that if $dp_z$ is onto for every
>   $z\in Z(p)$ where $Z(p)$ is the projective variety defined by $p$,
>   i.e. $Z(p)=\{[z_0:\dots:z_n]\in \mathbb P_\mathbb C^n:
>  p(z_0,\dots,z_n)=0\}$, then $Z(p)$ is a smooth manifold, and find its dimension.

My idea was to apply the preimage theorem to $p$, but the problem is that $Z(p)$ is not a subset of $\mathbb C^{n+1}$ so I cannot apply this theorem. My next attempt is the following: the map $p$ induces a well-defined map $P: \mathbb P_\mathbb C^n\rightarrow \mathbb P _\mathbb C^{m-1}$ (because the polynomial map is homogeneous). Now the preimage theorem can be applied. Note that $P^{-1}(0)=Z(p)$ and $0$ is a regular value of $P$; thus $Z(p)$ is a manifold of dimension $n-(m-1)=n-m+1$.

Is this a correct approach/solution?

Comment: Isn’t the dimension $2(n-m+1)$?

Comment: @Convex if you mean real dimension, then I guess yes; I meant complex dimension

Comment: The preimage theorem cannot be applied directly, because $0$ is not a point of projective space.

Comment: @danneks Oh, right, thanks. Then I don't know how to solve this at all.